# How to prevent gitlab autostart on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

I am running gitlab CE 8.2.0 on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

How can I prevent it from automatically starting on reboot?

I can't find anything relevant in `gitlab.rb`

Edit: why the negative vote? please leave a comment to explain, I am new to this site.

Comment: On CentOS there's a service called gitlab-runsvdir.
I guess it should be the same on Ubuntu, check in /etc/init.d dir

Comment: found the startup script: `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start`, managed by upstart through `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf`

Comment: Okay it's a bit different then. I guess it's due to the fact that CentOS is powered by SystemD, whereas Ubuntu is still on Upstart. Did it work ?

Answer (score 1):

To disable gitlab from autostarting in ubuntu 14.04

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.override
```

[how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)